# If $3c$ is a perfect square then why must $c$ be of form $3x^2$ for some $x$? ( $x,c$ integers)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For example $3c=36$,
then $36=3*4^2$ so $x=4$.

Comment: $36\neq3\cdot4^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Primes (such as $3$) have the property that if they divide a product, they divide (at least) one of the factors: If $p\mid ab$ then $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$.

Here we take $p=3$ and from the assumption $3c=m^2=m\cdot m$ conclude that $3$ divides one of the two factors on the right, that is $3\mid m$ at any rate. So $m=3x$ for some integer $x$, hence $3x=m^2$ turns into $3c=9x^2$, i.e. $c=3x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

This is because 3 is a prime, and for $3c$ to be a perfect square, $3|c$,...

Comment: So if we prime factorize 3c we must get another 3 out of the c.

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: I'm trying to get back into math.  Did alot of it years ago but have been computer programmer for 20 years and now looking maybe to teach high school.

Comment: yes I accept but do I have to press button on screen somewhere to do that?

Comment: you have to press the tick button on the top left of my answer @lunchman